# Kensai's Signature Weapon special abilities

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, prestige-class

Maximum Kensai's Signature Weapon Bonus is +10. However, maximum enhantment bonus is +5, so as Complete Warrior says "it can have special abilities that are the 
equivalent of additional bonuses". This special ability is, for example, *flaming*, which is equivalent of +1.

Do I need to apply maximum enhantment bonus to the weapon before applying any special ability to it, which means that I need at least 6 levels in Kensai to do it, or can do it at the very 1st level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The signature weapon then becomes a magic weapon (if it wasn’t already) and gains an enhancement bonus and/or special abilities.

Since “and/or” includes “or” as an option, the signature weapon could gain just “special abilities” from this feature. This is interesting because there is no mention of this following the usual rule requiring a +1 bonus on the weapon prior to applying special weapon abilities; as written, it seems you could produce a *flaming longsword* (which is ordinarily impossible; a *+1 flaming longsword* is the lowest you could usually get it).

But even if your DM decides that it still requires the minimum +1, you definitely do not need +5 to start applying special weapon abilities.

Comment: Or if you wanted to add cheese, a flaming, keen, warning, bane, morphing, vorpal longsword for a total +10